# Recursively get each element in a list of lists (Flattening isn't applicable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm creating lists of lists than can be of unlimited depth, for example:

```
[[[['Alpha'], ['Bravo']], ['Charlie']], [[['Delta'], ['Echo']], ['Foxtrot']]]
```

**I'd like to get to each element in the list.**
It's always a left-right situation on any level.

**EDIT:** The reason I'm creating those lists of lists is: I've found it a convenient way to record the parent-child relations between elements. **Flattening isn't applicable in this case**, as it disregards the relations between elements.

Thanks.

Note: There are a couple of similar questions here, but I'm pretty sure this isn't a dupe

Comment: process **how**? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists will iterate over the elements... using generators for example... or do you mean you want to process the **lists**...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: Why I'm creating those lists of lists: I've found it a way to record the parent-child relations between elements. Flattening isn't applicable in this case, as it disregards the relations between elements.

Is the downvote really applicable, @KaushikNP?

Comment: Whats the question

Comment: @NickA Recursively get (and print, for example) each element in the list

Comment: @user2426320 , seems fair I do a +1 there.

Comment: You wrote,"I'd like to get each element in the list".   The reason for the other comments giving pushback is that the enumerate IS a flattened list.

Comment: I do understand that you want to keep the original list as it is, i.e. not flattened. But could you please explain the difference between getting each element and flattening?

Answer (score 2):

Since `flattening` the list is not an option, you can traverse through the list `recursively`.

```
def traverse(l): 
    for i,ele in enumerate(l):  
       if len(ele)>1:  
          traverse(ele)  
       else:  
          print(ele)  

traverse(l)
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [[[['Alpha'], ['Bravo']], ['Charlie']], [[['Delta'], ['Echo']], ['Foxtrot']]] 
OUT : 
['Alpha']
['Bravo']
['Charlie']
['Delta']
['Echo']
['Foxtrot']
```

In case you want even the **Depth** of the **list element**, just change the function to :

```
def traverse(l, depth): 
    for i,ele in enumerate(l):  
       if len(ele)>1:  
          traverse(ele, depth+1)  
       else:  
          print(ele, depth+1)  

traverse(l, 0)
```

#driver values

```
OUT :
['Alpha'] 3
['Bravo'] 3
['Charlie'] 2
['Delta'] 3
['Echo'] 3
['Foxtrot'] 2
```